# Setting MATLAB's default colormap

Tags: matlab-figure

I am preparing some figures for a paper printed in black and white. I thought that easiest way to do so was to change the default colormap to gray.  However I'm stuck with the following error:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureColormap',gray); 

Error using set
Value must be either:
an Mx3 array of type single or double in the range [0 1]
an Mx3 array of type uint8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `rgb2gray` to convert from RGB. There are other such alternatives mentioned in the Image Processing Toolbox.